# Inserting an INDIRECT into another formula to replace fixed values

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do the following.

- Take a value in a defined cell
- Look up that value on another sheet called 'Updates'.
- Look across the row for the last non-empty cell
- Look up from there and return the header.

I know that if there was a defined range, the following formula works great for the last two steps.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(Updates!B3:E3<>0),Updates!B2:E2)
```

However I tried to make it more flexible with INDIRECT and came up with the abomination of a formula which I intended to just copy down.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/INDIRECT("Updates!B"&B5+2&":S"&B5+2<>0),Updates!$B$2:$S$2)
```

However this just returns a #REF error. Is this type of thing not possible or is there a simpler way to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: try this: `=INDEX(Updates!$1:$1,match("zzz",INDEX(Updates!A:s,MATCH(B5,Updates!B:B,0),0)))`  it is my best guess, without test data provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not closing the INDIRECT  statement before making the `<>0` test - so move that bracket to the left and it should work; ie

```
= LOOKUP(2,1/INDIRECT("Updates!B"&B5+2&":S"&B5+2) <>0, Updates!$B$2:$S$2)
```

Comment: That's a fair point but when I do close the brackets I just get "The formula you typed contains an error' box.

    =LOOKUP(2,1/INDIRECT("'Updates'!B"&B6+2&":S"&B6+2)<>0),Updates!$B$2:$S$2)